# Update using @Query not updating data in ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-update, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using ReactiveCrudRepository with Spring web flux. Following query is not updating data in a Postgres database with r2dbc. I tried initially without @Modifying also. I used this annotation with reference of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121620/spring-data-jpa-update-query-not-updating)

```
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("update company set deleted_at=current_timestamp, deleted_by=:deletedByUserId where id=:id")
Mono<Void> deleteById(Long id, Long deletedByUserId);
```

Comment: You are mixing JPA and Spring Data R2DBC annotations. Make sure to not use annotations for `javax.persistence` or `spring.data.jpa` with Spring Data R2dbc.

I changed the tags so they match your question. You might want to review those.

Comment: @JensSchauder I tried it first before applying org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying (@Modifying) also. It wasn't working in my case.

Comment: There is a `@Modifying` for R2DBC. Use that. Also make sure to subscribe to the result.

Answer (score 1):

In case of webflux R2DBC, need to subscribe for the result. In your case make sure that result is handled in calling method. OR if you are calling from repository/service handle result or return from repository or service.

```
@DeleteMapping("/company")
public Mono<Void> deleteCompany(@PathVariable Integer companyId) {
     Mono<Void> result = repository. deleteById("deletedUserName", companyId);
     return result;
}
```