# How to update spring jpa entity cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entity. When I use method `save()` of my `JpaRepository`, the record is inserting into database. Database has trigger, which modifies the record. But `save()`, and also `findById()` returns to me old unmodified value, from cache I suppose. Executing `EntityManager.clear()` solves problem, but I am not sure it is correct way.

How to tell `findById()` to do queries to database instead of cache? I have tried `@CacheEvict`, `@CachePut` annotations, but seems nothing works.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(schema="adm", name="datasets")
public class Dataset implements IEntity<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "guid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "schema_name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String schemaName;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description = "";

    @Column(name = "src_image_type")
    private String srcImageType;

    @Type(type= "com.luxms.bi.entity.jpa.BIJsonType")
    @Column(name = "images")
    private BIJson images = new BIJson();

    ......
}
```

Repo:

```
import com.luxms.bi.entity.BIDataset;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DatasetRepository extends JpaRepository<BIDataset, Integer> { }
```

Comment: Spring flushes the first level cache (creates a new session) for each transaction. Are you starting a new transaction for each time you call `findById`? If you already are doing (or trying to do) that, are you using Spring transaction management?

Comment: No, I am not. I will try, thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61008998/66686