# LazyInitializationException with Open in View turned on

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a Spring Boot 2.1.2 project with **spring.jpa.open-in-view=true**, we are (after a couple of years not having this kind of issue) being faced with a **LazyInitializationException** upon calling a lazy collection.

The stack trace with JPA debugging (logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=debug) indicates that, as expected, the session is not being closed during the execution of the request, independently of individual transactions being committed:

```
2021-03-22 23:37:25.198 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(211207390<open>)]
2021-03-22 23:37:25.199 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2021-03-22 23:37:25.199 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(211207390<open>)] for JPA transaction
2021-03-22 23:37:25.199 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2021-03-22 23:37:25.200 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@6f7a9974]
2021-03-22 23:37:25.200 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2021-03-22 23:37:25.201 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(211207390<open>)]
2021-03-22 23:37:25.202 DEBUG 22668 --- [io-8020-exec-10] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.opsfactor.planning.model.domain.cluster.produto.ClusterProdutos.regrasAlocacaoClusterProdutos, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:188)
    at com.opsfactor.planning.model.projection.configuration.parametros.ClusterEParametrosProjection.getClusterProdutosDeMaterial(ClusterEParametrosProjection.java:740)
```

Even though the session is not closed the error shows up, always at the same point. The entity and code being executed are:

```
@Entity
public class ClusterProdutos implements Serializable {
    
    ...

    ---------> collection generating error
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clusterProdutos",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<RegraAlocacaoClusterProdutos> regrasAlocacaoClusterProdutos = new HashSet<>();

    ...

}
```

I have not found any posts/comments on this kind of exception happening with **spring.jpa.open-in-view=true**, so more than just solving the issue I would like to understand the reason behind it. Probably EAGER fetching the collection or just making everything transactional will make the code run, but it will not answer the question.

So far we have tried to increase the connection timeout, idle timeout, max lifetime and maximum pool size - to no effect.

The error occurs both in my Windows machine and our AWS production server, which runs on their Linux flavour and the database is MySQL 8

**UPDATE:**

The error stops when I comment out the repository call below, which is made before the instantiation of the previous entity:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductionPlanLinhaRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductionPlanLinha,ProductionPlanLinhaCompositeKey> {

    ...

    @Transactional
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true) // https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation
    @Query("UPDATE ProductionPlanLinha ppl "
            + "SET ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoBaselineAtendida = ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoBaseline, "
            + "ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoItensNovosAtendida = ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoItensNovos, "
            + "ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoUpliftAtendida = ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoUplift, "
            + "ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoAjusteDemandaAtendida = ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoAjusteDemanda, "
            + "ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoAjusteSupplyAtendida = ppl.quantidadeSugestaoProducaoAjusteSupply "
            + "WHERE ppl.productionPlanLinhaCompositeKey.supplyPlan.id = :supplyPlanId")
    public void resetPlanoProducaoRestritoBySupplyPlanId(Long supplyPlanId);

    ...

}
```

Any ideas as to how we can keep the update query? Cache reset is a must, as it is not updated with the query.

Comment: I think, spring boot open in view JPA session is by default open true always, removing it from properties should not change anything, do you have custom transaction manager or configured session factory yourself? Please post your configurations also.

Comment: we don't use any custom transaction managers and never call a session factory directly. access to data is made exclusively from repositories with no manual session/transaction management (save for some methods annotated with @Transactional). I have included our application.properties in the post

Comment: Its very difficult to say what's going wrong here, I will advise you to trim down the source code in new project and use only problematic entities in that and check if it gives the same problem, if yes, then should raise issue with spring boot team.

Comment: I will try to comment successive code sections until the problem stops and then post the results

Comment: Just posted my findings : it seems that calls to @Modifying repository methods are closing the session

Comment: I think, `@modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)` triggers the flushing of entity manager, so all entities are gone from cache, hence `LazyInitilizationException`

Comment: shouldn't the correct behaviour be to re-initialize the collection with the current (already open) session?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the issue is not related to `Session` here, it's the modifying query which clears the persistence context and the object you are holding upto your web layer, is a detached object now.

If you check the class in error message `AbstractPersistenceCollection` it has this function which is called to check if `session` is there or not

```
protected boolean isConnectedToSession() {
        return session != null
                && session.isOpen()
                && session.getPersistenceContextInternal().containsCollection( this );
    }
```

As you can see this is the `&&` condition, the last condition is checking if persistence context contains the collection and this might be throwing error in your case irrespective of session is open or not.

Comment: I have posted this as an issue in spring data JPA : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2187 . My understanding is that if the cache has been cleared it should the ORM's job to reinitialize collections when required

Comment: I think you should raise it with hibernate team, it might not be related to spring jpa.

Comment: @epol that understanding is wrong. Entities not attached to a session don't get reattached automatically. And `clearAutomatically = true` does remove all entities from the session.

Comment: just got an answer from the Spring Data JPA team : 'The behaviour of lazy collections is the normal behaviour of JPA. See section 3.2.7 Detached Entities from the JPA Specification 2.2.'
From this one can either work with update queries without clearAutomatically = true - in which case a lot of care needs to be exercised as future queries / already loaded entities will be out of sync with the database - or just run all updates with clearAutomatically = true before instantiating the entities.

Answer (score -1):

I added the @Transactional(readOnly  = true)  to the businees layer method and it fixed it.

```
  /**
 * findUserById
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
@Transactional(readOnly  = true)
@Override
public UserDTO findUserById(Long id) {
```